# How to open new application in current activate desktop with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I want to open a new google chrome window when i press a shortcut key.

I have a LCD connected with MacBook, that means 2 screens. 
MacBook have Desktop 1 Desktop 2, LCD have Desktop 3 Desktop 4.

```
tell application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
    make new window
    open location "https://www.google.com/"
    activate
end tell
```

save this as Quick Action with Automator, and set the shortcut key in keyboard setting.

it works well on the LCD desktops, but can't open chrome on MacBook desktops.

I tried make desktop 1 focused and press shortcut key, It can only open new chrome in current desktop(3 or 4) which on the LCD, never open on the MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set newWindow to (make new window)
    repeat while loading of active tab of newWindow 
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    set URL of active tab of newWindow to "https://www.google.com/"
end tell
```

With both of your displays connected, and assuming you have the proper set up in System Preferences (as in the image below), you should just be able to right click Google Chrome icon in your dock and in the options menu... You can choose which display and desktop you want Google Chrome to be displayed.

[image]

[image]